# log to a file hosted on tomcat

Tags: java, logging, log4j, java.util.logging

I want to log my application output to a file hosted on my tomcat server. log4j.properties set is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/initiate.log
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

It does create `initiate.log` file but my log statements are not added to it. What is the issue? Or how will I set the properties using java `Logger` to output to fil

Comment: Can't be. As its my desktop and I am admin

Comment: Why you define the appender "log4j.appender.stdout" twice?

Comment: Are you setting `${catalina.home}` in your jvm arguments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a way to access file logger somewhere in your java code

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

private static Logger logger= Logger.getLogger("R");//fileLoggerName: R in this case
```

and then access the file like below

```
logger.error("Whatever message is!!"); 
//OR 
logger.info("message to write", exceptionObjectForCompleteTrace);
```